# ImportError: cannot import name exceptions FLASK - Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm working with SQLite and Flask in Python. My problem is that I'm trying to create a database but I get the error *"ImportError: cannot import name exceptions"*.

```
python db_create.py
```

**db_create.py**

```
#!flask/bin/python
from migrate.versioning import api
from config import SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from config import SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO
from app import db
import os.path
db.create_all()
if not os.path.exists(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO):
    api.create(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, 'database repository')
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO)
else:
    api.version_control(SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI, SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO, api.version(SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO))
```

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "db_create.py", line 2, in <module>
    from migrate.versioning import api
  File "/home/desarrollo3/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/migrate/versioning/api.py", line 33, in <module>
    from migrate.versioning import (repository, schema, version,
  File "/home/desarrollo3/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/migrate/versioning/schema.py", line 10, in <module>
    from sqlalchemy import exceptions as sa_exceptions
ImportError: cannot import name exceptions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this issue, I had to install the [sqlalchemy-migrate](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sqlalchemy-migrate/0.10.0) package:

```
pip install sqlalchemy-migrate
```